# How to Activate IMEI place order service in DHRU API

Tags: php, api, unlock

Hello everyone I am developing a website that provides unlock code to mobile user who request. but i am new in druv api so please can anyone provide a documentation or guide to use it.some error are listed below,
i am using dhru unlocking API for unlock mobile but  getting error when going to place imei order by using curl.

error is.

```
{"ID":"1234","IMEI":"111111111111119","ERROR":[{"MESSAGE":"ValidationError123","FULL_DESCRIPTION":"Service Not Active"}],"apiversion":"3.1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Realize this is a bit old, but it will probably help someone I'm sure. Here's the link to the api stuff http://kb.dhru.com/Dhru_Fusion/Developer_Resources

Also, I found it by googling "dhru fusion api" wasn't all that hard to find lol probably why this topic never got answered.